# Bitbucket Cloud - prevent creation of tags in repository

Tags: bitbucket

I'm trying to prevent pushing any tags to the repository

I tried using "Branch Permissions" to prevent the creation of `*` branches, but it doesn't seem to effect tags. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formal answer from Bitbucket:

This is currently not supported by Bitbucket cloud. It is only supported by Bitbucket Server

Comment: Linking to [BCLOUD-10967](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-10967) for issue tracking (vote for it!).  As of 2023-01-25 it has been moved to 'Reviewing' status.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern for tags is `refs/tags/*`, restrict access to that branch and it shouldn't work to push tags.

Additional info
[bitbucket/atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-i-block-all-tags-from-being-pushed-to-a-repository-822021700.html) seems to agree

Comment: This works for Bitbucket Server and not Bitbucket Cloud